# Large partition count performance impact

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have tables have millions of partitions.
Should I reduce partition count for performance?
As my experience of spark application or hive query system, too many partition was bad for performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have auto clustering on the table, it will not be auto defragmented. So if you write to the table frequently with small row counts, it will be in very bad shape.

Partition count impacts compile time badly, as every partition has metadata that is load to plan/optimize the query. I would suggest doing a rebuild test (select into a new transient table) and run some comparable queries to see the different in compile time.

We have a number of table that sorting (thus auto clustering) does not make sense for as the use pattern is always full-table scan, thus we just rebuild those tables on schedules to keep the partition count down, and for us, that rebuild cost is worth the performance gain.

As with everything Snowflake you should run a test, and see how it is for you. And monitor hot spots as they can and do change.

Comment: You are surely right about Defragmentation because it requires re-distributing data. And I already said, it is the clustering. On the other hand, your sample is wrong. You say "if you write to the table frequently with small row counts, it will be in very bad shape.". Create a table, insert 100 rows for 20 times, then select all rows, you will see the query will read only 1 partition). So Snowflake creates micro-partitions (it's a must), and maintain them (delete and merge if needed). If you say it must also defragment to be count as "management", it's ok :)

Comment: it seems we have lived different snowflake experiences. I was talking to the Snowflake Product Manger for Auto-clustering just last week, and they where talking about how they are think of making the defragmention part of auto-cluster (a relatively new behavior add to auto-clustering as a stand-a-long feature), because customers have tables that are fragmented, and rewritten terabyte tables is not free. But sure if you have a table with 2000 rows it might appear to have magic done to it.

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake, there are micro-partitions, and they are managed automatically. Therefore you do not need to worry about the number of micro-partition.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-micropartitions.html#what-are-micro-partitions

It says:

> Micro-partitioning is automatically performed on all Snowflake tables.
>   Tables are transparently partitioned using the ordering of the data as
>   it is inserted/loaded.

From this page, I understand that micro-partitions are managed by Snowflake, and you do not need to focus on reducing the partition count (this is the original question).

This should also help to understand the difference between clustering and micro-partitions:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/table-considerations.html#when-to-set-a-clustering-key

If you read the above link, you can see that it is not a must to define clustering on even large tables to get a good query performance!

As the original question about reducing the partition count, I also have to say that clustering does not always reduce the number of partitions, but it is another story.

Comment: They are not managed automatically. Unless you have auto-clustering turned on.

Comment: Micro-partitions and clustering are not same thing. Snowflake does not have traditional partitions. Micro-partitions are always generated for any table, and they are managed by Snowflake (do you create a partition for your table? no). Clustering is a feature to distribute data to this micro-partitions. They are strictly related but not the same things.

Comment: Your points by themselves are correct. But still are not the correct answer to the question. "Do lot of partitions impact performance?" "Yes" is the answer... the follow up question "Does Snowflake automatic manage those partitions for you?" the answer is "No" "If you use auto-clustering your partitions will get defragmented also, re-ordered" I was talking to the auto-clustering product manager at snowflake about this very thing last week...

Comment: to help translate gap, if the mirco-partitions where called micro-fragments, you would see I am not talking about classical partitions, just the many tiny files you have in S3/Azure/GC filesystem. And if the table is not rewrite nothing magically happens to those files, so they remain many. Now if you have Auto-clustering (or if you an old account you might have manual clustering, or you might be an old enough account that you memeber zero clustering and having to rewrite tables yourself to solve this fragmentation problem) then turning on auto-clustering would "help".

Comment: The way to use auto clustering to "help" would be if you have a `insert_time` column, then you auto cluster on that, and the net effect would be a defragmentation. When talking to the PM they said snowflake where thinking of separating out the defragmention from auto-clustering, to help tables that do not need sort, but are badly fragmented. If this is something important to you, I'd write to your customer-account-manger and tell them your interested.